# Button is clickable but doesn't work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I have this code but when I'm trying it on my phone doesn't do anything..
I tried the version on firebase website too but it doesn't work. I would really appreciate if you can help me guys!

I think that this is [the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAZ0k.jpg)
Can someone help me with it?

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Firebase mFirebase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        mFirebase = new Firebase("https://kip.firebaseio.com");
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }

    public void onClickLogin(View v){

        final String email = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
        final String password =((EditText) findViewById(R.id.password)).getText().toString();

        mFirebase.createUser(email, password, new Firebase.ResultHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                mFirebase.authWithPassword(email, password, null);
                System.out.println("Successfully created user account!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                mFirebase.authWithPassword(email, password, null);
                System.out.println("There was an error connecting!");
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Here is my XML

```
<Button 
    android:layout_width="300dp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/button_login" 
    android:text="@string/login" 
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
    android:textSize="16sp" 
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password"  
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp" 
    android:onClick="onClickLogin" 
    android:clickable="true" />
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "doesn't do anything"? Does your `onClickLogin()` method get executed? This is something you can most easily check in a debugger.

Comment: I click on it and doesn't show the message or even create the account. I really don't know what to do about it. Can you make an example that should work with my strings?

Comment: I highly suggest that you run through your code in a debugger. StackOverflow is not an efficient mechanism for debugging your code.

Comment: Where do you initialize a button? I would expect to see private Button mButton; somewhere in your code.

Comment: @tccpg288 You don't need to initialize a Button if you attach the listener via XML

Comment: What if you put a `Log.d("test", "test");` as the first line of the `onClickLogin` method. Will you see it in the Logcat?

Comment: Do you guys think that I might have missed something in Activity?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that https://kipster.firebaseio.com/ is not found...

Comment: @cricket_007 My bad I edited it to see if I have any problems if I put an incorrect url. I forgot to put the real url but it doesn't work even with the good one..

Comment: Like many already said: set a breakpoint at the first line of onClickLogin and use debug instead of run, or add a log statement and see if it appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final code and it works!!

```
protected EditText mEmail;
protected EditText mPassword;
protected Button mLogin;
protected Button mRegister;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Login);
    mRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Register);

    mLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://kip.firebaseio.com");

            String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            ref.authWithPassword(email, password, new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
                    System.out.println("User ID: " + authData.getUid() + ", Provider: " + authData.getProvider());
                    Intent activity = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(activity);

                }
                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    // there was an error
                }
            });

        }
    });

    mRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://kip.firebaseio.com");

            String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            ref.createUser(email, password, new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<Map<String, Object>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> result) {
                    System.out.println("Successfully created user account with uid: " + result.get("uid"));
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    // there was an error
                }
            });


        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Firebase mFirebase;
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        mFirebase = new Firebase("https://kip.firebaseio.com");
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        button.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final String email = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
                final String password =((EditText) findViewById(R.id.password)).getText().toString();

                mFirebase.createUser(email, password, new Firebase.ResultHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        mFirebase.authWithPassword(email, password, null);
                        System.out.println("Successfully created user account!");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                        mFirebase.authWithPassword(email, password, null);
                        System.out.println("There was an error connecting!");
                    }
                });



            }
        });


        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }


}
```

Comment: It doesn't work... but thank you!

Comment: 2 questions @AndreiNedelcu 
 - it's the button event fired?
 - It's some error while the firebug process is running?

Comment: What do you mean by fired? when I tried your code the app won't open.

Comment: @AndreiNedelcu are you getting some error? Add a breakpoint in your application (before `mFirebase.createUser` method) and debug your app, paste if your are getting some error (see in your log cat)

Comment: This won't work because your `findViewById` is outside the `onCreate`. And whether you assign the button via XML or Java, it shouldn't make any difference